# Dual Monitors on Optiplex 9020 DT

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dell-optiplex

I am trying to install a second monitor on my Optiplex 9020 DT (I'm using Windows 7 Professional).  Both are Dell U2412M Flat Panel Monitors.  I have one plugged in using a DVI and one with a VGA, as there aren't two DVI ports.  The one plugged in using the DVI is recognized and is just fine.  The other I can't get the computer to recognize at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Three native monitors on Dell OptiPlex 9010](http://superuser.com/questions/441378/three-native-monitors-on-dell-optiplex-9010)

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the Dell site - [How to Deal with Multi Monitor Setup and Other Video Issues on My Dell OptiPlex Desktop.](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN209307/en)

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of that, as he isn't talking about DisplayPort technology, even though some of the content might be relevant.